# Jenkins "selective" matrix build [matrix-project-plugin]

Tags: matrix, jenkins, continuous-integration

[Matrix](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin) plugin allows us doing multi-dimensional builds based on some user-defined or built-in axes. However when we trigger the matrix build, Jenkins starts build for all cartesian product builds. ***QUESTION:*** I wonder is there a way to trigger a build for a single matrix entry or am I on a wrong path?

**Some visualization**:

axis 1 variables (branch) -> master branch1 branch2

axis 2 variables (app type) -> api web

axis 3 variables (deploy target) -> test stage live

In this specific case jenkins comes up with a 3-dimensional cube of jobs containing 3x2x3=18 builds in it, and when I trigger build that matrix project all of them starts. What I want here is, I should able to select axis variable for each axis (ie from multiselect list), and based on those selections jenkins should build only corresponding items. For instance;

axis 1 -> branch1

axis 2 -> api

axis 3 -> test stage

Hence jenkins should execute only 2 jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [Matrix Combination Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Combinations+Plugin) which will prompt you for the combinations you want

> This plugin allows a user to choose which matrix combinations he wants
>   to run, as opposed to the default behaviour where jenkins runs all
>   combinations: Using:
>
> After clicking the build, the user gets a html table with a checkbox
>   for each matrix combination.
>
> After clicking the submit button, only checked combinations will run.

Comment: Thanks @KeepCalmAndCarryOn ! I will try out asap. In advance do you know whether it can be triggered by `POST` req like regular parametrized builds?